# Parse condition statement uisng javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to parse below conditional query into javascript array.

```
project=test AND client="clinical and connection" 
OR module IN ("login",'rigister and list') 
AND start_date between "10-12-2016" AND "11-12-2016" 
ORDER BY id asc
```

OUTPUT

```
["project", =, "test", "AND", "client", "clinical and connection", OR.....]
```

Comment: How would be the IN statement evaluated? A new array?

Comment: can you split the string with `'  '`?

Comment: Here's some SQL(?) put this in an array...erm, what? It's not like there is a standard SQL -> array config.

Comment: But then how does `"clinical and connection"` end up in there @zabusa, this question is very odd. I'm mostly confused who on earth upvoted this...very quickly...like there is some kind of (lets call it) a [sock puppet account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259949/is-there-a-mechanism-to-detect-sock-puppets) voting on all the OPs questions.

Comment: @Liam not only that but `project=test` also wont work